# Nginx (1.14) ssl installation on port 3443 not working

Tags: nginx, ssl

Here is my nginx `/etc/nginx/conf.d/my_domain-ssl.conf` file.

```
server {

listen 3443;

ssl on;

ssl_certificate /home/ubuntu/my_domain_chain.crt;

ssl_certificate_key /home/ubuntu/ssl/mydomain.co.key;

root /var/www/html;

server_name mydomain.co www.mydomain.co;

}
```

So this way I am trying to install ssl on port 3443(instead of 443). My ssl is all fine. But I still get this "Your connection is not private" error (NET::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID). This means its still using the old(expired) ssl certificate.
Clearly the file above is not being respected(nginx is reading the ssl certificate from configuration specified in some other file).

So how do I resolve this?

Comment: *"Clearly the file above is not being respected"* - or it is respected but you've put the correct file in the wrong place. The content of the file you use here is not known.. Another option:  you did not restart nginx after change. Too much unknown.

Comment: *"gives location of this file "* - which just says that there is a file with this name. It does not say if this is actually the intended file. nginx just serves whatever you provide, even if it is an expired certificate.

Comment: Correct, it opens the file. But this still says nothing about the contents of the file. If you put an expired certificate in the right place it will serve the expired certificate and `nginx -t` will not complain